# How to track history of a record of a custom object in apex class?

Tags: apex, opportunity-history

I want to track history(History which is shown below every record in salesforce user interface) of a record in apex class.  How can i do this? What will be used in SOQL query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have field history tracking enabled for an object then the changes are stored in a special history table for that particular object.

The naming of these tables follows a simple convention so should be easy to find. For standard objects the name of the history table follows the format: '*ObjectNameHistory*' so for the `Account` object the history table is `AccountHistory`

For custom objects the name of the convention simply replaces the '*c*' on the end of the API name with '*History*'. So, for a custom object call `My_Custom_Object__c` the history table is called `My_Custom_Object__History`

It's worth having a look through the metadata for your org using something like [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) so that you can see the history tables and the fields that they contain.

Answer (score 10):

History is available on History Enabled Objects as child Object  and its relationship name is `Histories`. You can query this child object by inner SOQL query like this:

`SELECT Id, Name, (Select OldValue, NewValue From Histories) FROM My_Custom_Object__c`

However you cannot do:

`[SELECT id FROM History]`

Comment: You can query each object's History table directly, have a look at @SMGoodyear 's answer.