# Accessing editdate for a field through Api

Tags: api

I am trying to pull the edit date of a customfield in salesforce through Soql. It only appears when I generate a report around that custom field. If there isnt a way is there some kind of work around that I can do to pull past edit dates?

thank you

Comment: Do you have "Track Field History" set to true on your object?

Comment: Yes it is track history enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that by running a SOQL query on the custom object history table:

`SELECT Field, NewValue, OldValue, CreatedDate FROM Your_Custom_Object__History`

Where Field is the field API name that has been changed (updated), new and old values are obviously the values that have changed and the `CreatedDate` field represents the date/time when the field was changed.

If you want to get the last date when the record has been updated in general then you can order by CreatedDate DESC in the query, LIMIT 1 and get the first record.

> EDIT: Just found another post on this site - [How to track history of a record of a custom object in apex class?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/how-to-track-history-of-a-record-of-a-custom-object-in-apex-class)
>
> EDIT 2: If you want to obtain information about a particular field for the object, just add it in the WHERE clause in the query `WHERE Field = Field_Api_Name`

Comment: Im a bit confused by custom object vs custom field. The editdate I want to get is for the custom field name Funded__c. It's a field in Account. The Funded__c is track history enabled. 
Do you mean:
Select Funded__c, New Value, OldValue, CreatedDate From Funded__History

Comment: The query on the History object returns all the fields that have history tracking enabled for your custom/standard object and also lists which field was changed when as well as their old/new values and some additional information.

Comment: The query for that would be : `SELECT CreatedDate, OldValue, NewValue FROM AccountHistory WHERE Field = 'Funded__c'`