# How to track a field history of a custom object via Api?

Tags: api, custom-object

how  to track Field History via Api on custom object?

sorry that I'm unclear: I'm not developer.

Well to sum up : 
-i have activated my web service on salesforce.com with my website 
-i have a custom field called: Price_c and i would display it to my website using API (i have tracked  already this field( Price_c) on my org)

do you have some example code to do that  ?

Comment: Are you asking how to access the Field History of a custom object via the API?

Comment: Yes, i need to access a custom field and save it to my website. Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot give more details and share some of the code you have already written, it will be hard to help you.

Every object in SFDC has an history object(provided you enabled field history tracking on it) from where you can retrieve its history information. 
Check this answer for details. 
[How to track history of a record of a custom object in apex class?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/how-to-track-history-of-a-record-of-a-custom-object-in-apex-class)

Now if you have an external application and need to access this. Then use either the soap or rest API and access this information.

If you have never done this before, then check these links which shows how you can access SFDC through C# or Java.

**Login:**
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_login.htm

http://www.munsplace.com/blog/2013/07/08/getting-started-with-salesforce-and-c/

**Query:**
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_query.htm

Comment: Richard N, I want to know more about this kind of action in the platform. With your links it's possible to use only C or Java programming language. I have a similar situation of Paolo...and I'm using PHP code and WebListing's calls.
But no guide or example helps me to resolve my problem!